# is there anyway to delete downloaded dynamic module (apk) file from device memory?

Tags: android, dynamic, module

I'm trying to use dynamic delivery module that stored some data. I've already success install and access data on this module from my base apps.
the next process is I want to delete downloaded module file (maybe in .apk file or something else) from my device memory.
Does anyone here know where this downloaded module file is stored?
is it possible if we want to delete this file? because in my opinion if we don't delete this file it will lead bigger size on disk, especially dynamic module that contain big data.

Could please anyone give me any information about this?
thanks.

Comment: I've checked using root device and I found where those file are stored.

Comment: You should be able to uninstall modules using SplitInstallManager. See documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#uninstall_modules